# Flash in VC++ Documentation

Tags: windows, activex, visual-c++, flash

I am trying to host a flash object inside an CAxWindow, I have managed to insert a shockwaveflash (SWF) and its working fine. I am trying to find all available API's that are available in the flash ocx. I am unable to find any documentation for the functions in the IShockwaveFlash interface.

I know that Adobe doesn't have a documentation for using flash in VC++ but I was wondering if anyone can point me to a place where I can find an UNOFFICIAL documentation for flash.ocx or code samples as the only API that I could find and I'm currently using is "PutMovie".

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you are #importing the OCX you can look in the auto generated header files - or use OleSpy - a tool thats bundled with VC - to see all the exposed methods on the shockwaveflash.shockwaveflash control

Comment: Yup its working fine, is there any good samples out there that does more than just embedding an SWF in a window, would love to see something that handles events between an SWF and the main application.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in VB.NET.

If you want, you can also open up Visual Basic (or C#) and use Intellisense to see what methods and attributes are available to you. I'm not sure that there is any documentation.

Comment: Seems that I had a problem with my VC, Reinstalled and now I can see the methods, intellisense did not work on the IShokwaveFlash object, and I couldn't open the tlh file to view the APIs.... now its time for trial and error.